# How to filter the terms to a special custom taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy, query, terms, php

I do have a custom taxonomy called "countries". With the code below I get for each term (country) the number of its published posts in brackets, like the following:

- Canada (3)
- USA (5)
- Italy (2)
- Cambodia (4)
- etc.

How is it possible to filter these countries to a special continent (e.g. Asia), which I have in another taxonomy called "continent"? Please see below in code as [IF_IN_TAXONOMY 'continents' WITH TERM 'Asia'].

```
<?php 
 $terms = get_terms('countries'); 
 if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) && [IF_IN_TAXONOMY 'continents' WITH TERM 'Asia']){ 
 echo '<ul>'; 
 foreach ( $terms as $term ) { 
 $term = sanitize_term( $term, 'countries' ); 
 $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'countries' ); 
 echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '&nbsp;('     .$term->count . ')' . '</a></li>'; 
 } 
 echo '</ul>';
 }
 ?>
```

I tried the functions "is term", "has_term", "term_exists" and tried it in a query "if (is_tax( 'continents', 'Asia' )", but nothing is working.

Comment: why not make countries children of continents in one taxonomy?

Comment: I also thought about this solution. It is just not practicable for my problem, because the world has almost 200 countries. And as I am catching the countries through metaboxes in the backend, the "continents-countries" checkbox would be too long. Please let me know if you see a big mistake in my thoughts.

Comment: you can use a taxonomy without using the taxonomy's default meta box. if a post only has a single continent / country, I would put all top level terms (continents) in a select menu within a custom meta box, and upon selection of continent populate a dropdown of its child country terms in another select menu via ajax.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. As there are several other taxonomy terms for each post (e.g. attractions), I cannot subordinate all terms to one parent taxonomy. Is there really no chance to filter the term slugs according to their published posts. E.g. all posts which are published in both Canada and USA have the same continent ;-)

Comment: I'm not suggesting putting all terms in a single taxonomy, just ones that are related to each other (continents / countries). anything is possible, but trying to glean relationship of two taxonomies by the posts they are related to is an order of magnitude less efficient query-wise.

Comment: I think your idea is the best solution to get what I need. As this requires a bigger change in my current structure, I thought there is maybe a quick code fix available. Many thanks for your support.